# Determine if the page is Publishing Page or Wiki page using JavaScript

Tags: 2013

Is there a way to check if the current page is a Wiki page or a Publishing Page using Client side methods in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the PnP JavaScript Library to check the page type.

We can determine the Page type by using Content Type Id,

- **Wiki Page**  - content type id starts with "0x010108"
- **Web Part page**  - Content type id starts with "0x010109"
- **Publishing Page** will have the Property called PublishingPageLayout field.

***Example 1: ( Determine based on Content type id)***

```
$pnp.sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Pages/PublishingPage.aspx").listItemAllFields.select('ContentTypeId,PublishingPageLayout').get().then(function(data) {
    if (data.ContentTypeId.startsWith("0x010108"))
        console.log('Wiki Page');
    else if (data.ContentTypeId.startsWith("0x010109"))
        console.log('Web Part Page');
    else {
        if (data.PublishingPageLayout != undefined)
            console.log('Publishing Page');
        else
            console.log('Others');
    }

});
```

***Example 2: (Determine based on Page Field name)***

```
$pnp.sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sitepages/testpnp.aspx").listItemAllFields.select('wikiField,PublishingPageLayout').get().then(function(data) {
    if (data.WikiField != undefined && data.WikiField != null)
        console.log('Wiki Page');
    else if (data.PublishingPageLayout != undefined)
        console.log('Publishing Page');
    else
        console.log('Nor wiki or Publishing Page');

});
```

To run the above code in on-premise environment, add the below code to the top of above examples,

```
$pnp.setup({
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    },
});
```

To know more about PnP JS library, click https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-JS-Core